# How to get gitlab ci variables when merge request is merged?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wish to get $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE and $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_URL when merge request is merged, however i got two empty string. I've checked the doc of gitlab and got this:

[image]

So is there any other way to get the information i need after merge request is merged? Thanks for any comment!

Answer (score 1):

> "when merge request is merged"

That looks like a [merge result pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html), one of the [three type of merge requests pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#types-of-merge-request-pipelines). It runs on the *result* of combining the source branch’s changes with the target branch.

But:

- it is only for Premium GitLab
- it needs to be activated ("Enable merged results pipelines.")

Comment: How would a merge result pipeline be triggered _just_ when the merge request is merged, though?

Comment: @swimmer Not sure, but I suspect [those variables might need to be involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72390078/6309).